# Fatal error throwing in codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using php version 7.

I am getting following error when run organization_list function

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Organization::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 52
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in  organization_model.php
```

Controller

```
public function organization_list()
    {  
        $data= $this->Organization_model->get_organization();

    }
```

Model

```
public function get_organization(){
        $SQL = "SELECT org_id,org_name FROM inv_organization WHERE org_status ='1' ";
        $query = $this->db->query($SQL); 
        $userdata= $query->result_array(); 
        return $userdata;
    }
```

Comment: did you load your database?

Comment: Yes Regolith.I load database

Comment: try checking this In config/autoload.php you have this $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that you did not loaded to Database.
You can load your database in contorller like:

```
$this->load->database();
```

Or in autoload.php like below:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you load database in your `autoload` 
try adding `database` in your library which is in `application/config/autoload.php'

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

or you can see [more of database](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)